# Getting wrong results with Perl subroutine

Tags: perl

I have a test file that looks like this:

```
my $int = new Services::Plugins::FTP::ftp;
$int->AddUser("durr");
```

The module has this code:

```
sub AddUser {

my( @username ) = @_;
print "@_\n";  

}
```

But my results looks like:
    Services::Plugins::FTP::ftp=HASH(0x2490160)durr

I just want 'durr'.

Why am I getting the extra stuff?

Answer (score 9):

You're dealing with object-oriented Perl. If you call a function on an object instance, as in your case with `$instance->function()`, then the very first parameter is the reference to the instance itself. It is most often called `$self`.

A commonly used idiom is to write instance methods like this:

```
sub some_method {
  my ($self, @args) = @_;
}
```

I suggest you read up on Perl's object-oriented system in the [perlootut man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html) (a good tutorial).

Answer (score 5):

The first argument to `$foo->bar()` is `$foo`

```
sub AddUser {
    my($self, @username ) = @_;
    print "@_\n";  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using Object Oriented approach (`$int->AddUser("durr")` is a *method* invocation). When calling a method, the first argument is always the object or the class the method should be applied to.